# How do I turn off row selection in a C# ListView -- specifically the dotted outline!

Tags: c#, listview

I have a ListView control that is in FullRowSelect mode, MultiSelect off and using the "Details" View mode. When the user clicks on a row, it highlights the row in blue, which is fine, But when I programatically turn off the selection by setting the row's "Selected" field to false, the blue highlight does go away, but it leaves a dotted outline around the row.

How do you turn off the dotted outline??

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dotted line disappears when another control is in focus. You can achieve this by calling the Focus() method on another control. As far as I know, there is no simple way to permanently get rid of the dotted outline.

If you *really* want to get rid of the line, you'll have to set the OwnerDraw property to true and provide handlers for DrawItem and DrawSubItem.

Comment: Thanks, setting another control to have the focus worked for me, and got rid of the blasted dotted line...